# minimal normal subgroup of a chief factor of soluble group $ G $ is a minimal normal normal subgroup of $ G $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ G $ is a soluble group. Let $ K/L $ be a chief factor of $ G $. Let $ M $ be the smallest normal subgroup of $ K $ such that $ K/M $ is nilpotent and $ M \neq 1 $. assume $ M/N $ be a chief factor of $ G $. Why $ M/N $ is a minimal normal subgroup of $ G $ ? $ C_{K}(M/N) $ is normal in $ G $?

Comment: $M/N$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G/N$, not of $G$. Yes, $C_K(M/N)$ is normal in $G$, because $K,M$ and $N$ are all normal.

Comment: @DerekHolt I think this answer isn't true. Since $ M $ is a normal subgroup of $ K $ then $ C_{K}(M/N) $ is a normal subgroup of $ K  $, not of $ G $. ( see Rose, A course on group theory, $ 390 (i) $ ).

Comment: But $C_K(M/N) = K \cap C_G(M/N)$ is the intersection of two normal subgroups of $G$, and so it is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: You should read what you have written more carefully. You have written "and $\Phi(G)$", which makes no sense. Also, you have mentioned a subgroup $L$ but then said no more about it, so why mention it?